# angularjs how to access scope inside controller's behavior

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have a problem while accessing $scope inside controller's behavior. code is like below.

```
<body id="main_body" ng-controller="FormController as frmCtrl">
<form id="form_991905" class="appnitro" name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && frmCtrl.doLogin()" novalidate>
    <div class="form_description">
        <h2>Login Form</h2>     
    </div>
    <ul>                
        <li id="li_1" >
            <label class="description" for="username">Username </label>
            <div>
                <input name="username" class="element text medium crequired email" type="email" ng-model="login.username" form-validator />
                <div class="errBx"></div>
            </div>
        </li>       
        <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="password">Password </label>
            <div>
                <input name="password" class="element text medium crequired" type="text" ng-model="login.password" form-validator/>
                <div class="errBx"></div>
            </div>
        </li>               
        <li class="buttons">            
            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

i want to access the $scope.login.username inside the method

```
controller code..... 

this.login = function(){
   console.log($scope.login.username);
}

// controller code
```

Comment: What problem you have?

Comment: Also when you are using controllerAs `frmCtrl`, you must prefix the ng-model with that. So it must be frmCtrl.login.username , Inside your controller it must be `this.login.username`

Comment: as i mentioned i want to access $scope variable inside that controller's method. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using "controllerAs" syntax, so there is no `$scope` available. In the view you can access it via `frmCtrl.login.username` or in the contoller you can try `this.login.username`.

You can learn more about it here: http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Comment: i went through the article, but i need to update $scope.xyz rather the ng-model value. is it possible?

Comment: There is no $scope value when using constrollerAs syntax... You can assign any property to `this` and use it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ctrl as` syntax, therefore your `ng-model` show be as follows:

```
ng-model="frmCtrl.login.password"
```

And function should change to:

```
this.login = function(){
   console.log(this.login.username);
}
```